# jQuery: “change” event on file input element does not fire in IE but working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have file input element which get clicked but after selecting file, change event does not fire in Internet Explorer but it is working fine in Chrome.

Below is my code

```
file_upload = '<input type="file" id="FileUpload" name="FileUpload" class="btn btn-default fileUploadReader"/>';

$("#FileUpload").change(function () {
    alert("Change Event");
});
```

Comment: which version of IE are you using?

Comment: I have got the solution. Thanks!

Comment: sounds great! Good luck

Comment: Well what was the solution?

Comment: @shivanisurana What was the solution

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in Internet Explorer, the `.change()` event on radio buttons doesn’t get fired properly, or at least it doesn’t behave the same was as it does in the other browsers.

There is however a relatively easy way to get around the problem, that is to handle the  `.click()` event, and then, just `.blur()` and `.focus()` the control – this will cause the `change()` event to be fired:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#FileUpload').click(function () {
        // Cause the change() event

        this.blur();

        this.focus();
   });
  $('#FileUpload').change(function() {

    // Handle .change() event as normal....

  });

});
```